# Recurrent sequence of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

Let $A, X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $det(A) \ne 0$.

Define the following reccurence:
$$X_{k+1} = X_k + X_k(I-AX_k)$$

**Prove** $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} X_k = A^{-1} \iff \rho(I-AX_k) < 1$$
where $\rho(B)$ means the biggest eigenvalue (in abs value) of the matrix $B$.

Any hints on how to prove it?